# Regex for a different pattern having multiple conditions

Tags: regex, multiple-conditions

I am looking for a regex for a completely different condition. My expression require-

1. Total length must be 6 or 7 or 8 characters.
2. a gap (space character) must be included.
3. Inward code, the part to the right of the gap, must always be 3 characters.
4. First character of the inward code must be numeric.
5. Second and third characters of the inward code must be alpha.
6. Outward code, the part to the left of the gap, can be 2, 3, or 4 characters.
7. First character of the outward code must be alpha.

I need expression to be like this-  BH6 5BG or b6 7ba or CH11 2ab

Alphabets can be lower case or upper case and first character should be an alphabet and after space three characters are allowed in which the first one should be a number.

I have made regex which include only first condition - `^(\d{6}|\d{7}|\d{8})$`

I am very confused in regex. Can anybody help me in building regex for the above conditions?

Comment: Please provide an example of acceptable string according to your pattern requirement.

Comment: I added the example expression. @Dhaval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex expression should work:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]{1,3}\s\d[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

[image: Explaination]

Comment: I added more example in the question. Could you help in achieving that

Comment: I tested all the 3 examples in your question, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do it for you:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3} \d[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

It matches

- `^` start of line
- `[a-zA-Z]` an alpha character - upper or lower case.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}` an alpha character - upper or lower case - or a digit, repeated 1-3 times.
- a space
- `\d` a digit
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` an alpha character - upper or lower case - repeated 2 times.
- `$` end of line

[Some examples at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bD4uN6/3).

Comment: I have more elaborated my requirement, Could you help in that @ ClasG

Comment: I'm confused - I believe my regex fulfills all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
/^[a-z].{1,3}\s\d[a-z]{2}$/i
```

Breakdown:

```
^                               #start of line
 [a-z]                          #alpa
      .{1,3}                    #from 1 to 3 of any char
            \s                  #a whitespace char
              \d                #a digit
                [a-z]{2}        #2 of any aplha
                        $       #end of line
                         i      #case insensitive
```

Comment: @ClasG hence the use of the `i` modifier so the regex is case insensitive.

Comment: So you're assuming it's javascript, or...?

Comment: @ClasG Well, OP is saying nothing about the language used, so PCRE expression sounds OK to me.

Comment: My point is, different languages have different ways of setting the *case insensitive flag*. And not all languages expresses a regex using `/.../`. I'm just saying that to be more generic, as the question is, your answer shouldn't assume things that are language dependent.

Comment: @ClasG PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) is a norm in itself, probably the most used. So it makes sense for a generic question without specific language tag to answer with this notation. (and in brief, I know only python and javascript where you can't use 'pure' PCRE syntax)

Comment: @ClasG I assumed that PCRE would be a good start as you assumed that the second part of what OP call the *Outward* should be alpha. There is not problem with both first or second assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?i)[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,3}\\s[0-9][a-z]{2}$
```

`(?i)` --> As alphabets can be lower case or upper case.

`\\s` --> For exactly one whitespace/gap.

*I have checked it using Java.

Comment: @Tensibai appreciate for that.